# virtualhost problem with apache

Tags: centos, php, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

I'm setting up a server with centos 7 and I have already installed Apache and php. I have tried to set-up a virtual-host to avoid "localhost/xxx.xxx", but now I cannot access to local-host any more. But, if I write the website that I set for the virtual-host and then I go back to the previous page Apache work and it open the php page that I was trying to open.
I have tried to delete the virtual host that I  have set but I don't remember how to do this.

Comment: did this solved your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

This is **normal** if you see it. Since it is the first virtual host entry it will show local host.

but still you can set that up in `httpd.conf`,

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
    ServerAdmin localhost
    DocumentRoot /path/to/htdocs/
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

To run projects like `http://yourwebsite.com` locally

```
<VirtualHost somewebsite.com:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/htdocs/yourwebsiteFolder
    ServerName www.yourwebsite.com
    ServerAlias yourwebsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

then restart httpd daemon using `sudo systemctl restart httpd.service`

[VirtualHost Examples](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) will help you more.